# How did Kaguya defeat Jigen/Isshiki after they came to earth?

Tags: boruto

How did Kaguya defeat Jigen/Isshiki?
They say that Isshiki is one of the most powerful of his clan. How did Kaguya beat him?

Answer (score 0):

It's not confirmed exactly how he got defeated just yet. And please correct me if I am wrong, but according to Amado, Isshiki dropped his guard and got attacked suddenly. Also, we don't know if he is one of the most powerful in the Otsutsuki Clan, but out of all revealed members, I say he is THE most powerful, I mean, even Naruto and Sasuke had a hard time against him, as Jigen too.

Comment: When Kaguya defeated Isshiki, Isshiki was almost DEAD So he had to go to another body nearby to hide which sadly was Jigen a Novice monk Who happened to be nearby and He kinda Took over Jigen but not like with the karma seal just because he was in his brain. So After some time, he put a karma seal on Jigen's chin Later (I don't know what he did) but He actually reincarnated as Jigen using Jigen as his vessel.

Answer (score 0):

Considering how strong Kaguya is, even without amps, it is not impossible to think that she could at least badly damage Isshiki, off-guard or not. A lot of people tend to downplay Kaguya by saying nonsense like Base Momoshiki being stronger than her, but there is absolutely 0 evidence of it outside of a very vague statement by Sasuke, and given their feats and showings that makes it clearer even more so. This is also proven indirectly when there many statements of Naruto having gotten rusty ever since he became Hokage, and thus struggling with Momoshiki who is weaker than Kaguya.